# charset for spanish windows

Tags: character-encoding

what is the charset for spanish windows?

Answer (score 12):

`Spanish (es)    iso-8859-1, windows-1252`

Comment: Specifically windows code page 1252, which is not quite the same as ISO-8859-1 (the meaning of bytes 0x80 to 0x9F differ).

Answer (score 11):

The only correct, acceptable character set nowadays is the Universal Character Set (UCS), and the only correct, acceptable encodings are Unicode Transformation Formats (UTF).

One of the worst misfeatures Windows has is a silly notion of a locale having several character sets and encodings associated to it: an 8-bit legacy so-called "OEM" character set that comes from the DOS days, an 8-bit legacy so-called "ANSI" character set that comes from the early Windows days, and so-called "wide character" UTF-16 Little-Endian, which is what Windows supports when applications are "Unicode". While the former so-called "OEM" thing is left for DOS applications, most of the Windows API is annoyingly duplicated with "A" (ANSI) functions and W (wide char) functions.

In the case of the Spanish locale, the "OEM" character set is CP850, the "ANSI" character set is CP1252, and of course there's UTF-16 Little-Endian which is what you should be using.

My recommendation is that you avoid CP1252 and CP850 like the plague and use UTF-16LE, as well as develop your applications with Unicode semantics and conventions. Some applications also support UTF-8, which is more convenient for European languages.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% on topic but probably very useful to some who will arrive here by a Google search, as I did: ÁáÉéÍíÓóÚúÑñ¡¿

Comment: This isn't in any way related to the question.

Comment: No, it's related to a likely Google search that brings you to this page.

Answer (score -1):

include meta tage in header file.
`<meta charset="iso-8859-1">`

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: What does this even mean?

Comment: The is correct, acceptable character set   Universal Character Set (UCS), and the  correct, acceptable encodings are Unicode Transformation Formats (UTF).